# Autogenerate seats in django mode

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I'm developing a bus reservation website using Django. I have two model files in different Django apps. One of the model class is Bus and another one is seats. There is capacity integerfield in bus class. I want that when a bus is created in the database, automatically a loop runs and creates the seats equal to the capacity in the bus class. Maybe you'll get a clearer view after looking at my models files.

> \src\book\models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from web.models import Bus, Route

class Booking(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Booking"
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #session = models.ForeignKey(sessions.Sessions)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=(('Mr', 'mr'), ('Mrs', 'mrs'), ('Ms', 'ms'),))
    age = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Seat(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Seat"
    for seats in range(1,int(float(Bus.capacity)+1.0)):   
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)



class Ticket(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Ticket"
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat)
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus)
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

> \src\web\models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Route(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Routes"

    BUSFROM = (
    ('Delhi', 'Delhi'),
    ('Jaipur', 'Jaipur'),
    ('Ajmer', 'Ajmer'),
    )

    BUSTO = (
    ('Ajmer', 'Ajmer'),
    ('Chandigarh', 'Chandigarh'),
    ('Delhi', 'Delhi'),
    )

    route_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)    
    location_from = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=BUSFROM)
    location_to = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=BUSTO)    
    route_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', editable=False)


    def __str__(self):
        if self.location_from == self.location_to:
            raise ValidationError('To and From Can\'t be the same')
        self.route_name = '{0}-{1}'.format(str(self.location_from), str(self.location_to))
        return self.route_name


class Bus(models.Model):

    BUSTYPE = (
    ('Volvo', 'Volvo'),
    ('Ordinary', 'Ordinary'),
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Bus"
    type_of_bus = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=BUSTYPE)
    bus_registration = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    capacity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bus_number = models.IntegerField()
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route,)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(str(self.bus_number), self.type_of_bus, self.route)
```

As you can see in the book\models.py, the for loop fails for the obvious reason of deferred objects.

Also, I want to create a frequency class in web\models.py for adding the frequency of the bus. If I make a datetime field then I would have to repeat each bus object again and again for every date which is not very convenient. SO any suggestions are welcome. Let me know if there is any other file that you need to see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the most elegant solution for your issue is [django post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save).

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Bus(models.Model):
    # ... fields here

class Seat(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus)
    # ... 

# function to create seats
@receiver(post_save, sender=Bus)
def create_seats(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for seat in range (0, instance.capacity):
            instance.seat_set.create( )
```

Another solution is to overwrite Bus save method.

Comment: it worked. Thanks a ton! can you please explain what you did? Also if I want to add frequency to the bus model, do you have any suggestion how to do it?